# Cloudant search document by attributes of nested objects

Tags: indexing, couchdb, cloudant, nosql

My documents in cloudant have the following structure

```
{
 "_id"      : "1234",
 "name"     : "test",
 "objects"  : [
   {
     "type"  :  "TYPE1"
     "time"  :  "1215
   },
   {
     "type"  :  "TYPE2"
     "time"  :  "1115"
   }
 ]
}
```

Now I need to query my documents by a list of types.

Examples

1) If I would query with **TYPE1** then all the documents where there is an object with this type would return. (The example doc would return)

2) If I would query with **TYPE1** and **TYPE3** it would return all documents which contain either of them (The example doc would return)

3) If I would query with **TYPE3**, **TYPE4** and **TYPE5** it would return all documents which contain either of them (The example doc would not return)

How would the code in the _design document look like and how would my API request look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use [Cloudant Search](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search).

Sample design document named `types`, which indexes each `type` property in your `objects` array

```
{
 "_id": "_design/types",
 "views": {},
 "language": "javascript",
 "indexes": {
  "one-of": {
   "analyzer": "standard",
   "index": "function (doc) {\n  for(var i in doc.objects) {\n    index(\"type\", doc.objects[i].type);  \n  }\n}"
  }
 }
}
```

Query examples:

Search for one key (`type=val`)

```
GET https://$HOST/$DATABASE/_design/$DDOC/_search/one-of?q=type%3ATYPE1
```

Search for multiple keys (`type=val1 OR type=val2`)

```
GET https://$HOST/$DATABASE/_design/$DDOC/_search/one-of?q=type%3ATYPE1%20OR%20type%3ATYPE2
```

Search for multiple keys (`type=val1 AND type=val2`)

```
GET https://$HOST/$DATABASE/_design/$DDOC/_search/one-of?q=type%3ATYPE1%20AND%20type%3ATYPE2
```

To include the documents in the response append `&include_docs=true`.